# How to dynamically read VBA macro strings from document body at runtime?

Tags: vba, ms-word

VBA is giving errors when I try to move strings into body of the document and reference them.

An example of what I'm trying to do. Consider the following macro:

```
Public Function Foo() As Variant
    Set Bar = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Bar.Run ("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe")
End Function
```

I am trying to move strings such as "WScript.Shell" and "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe" into the body of the Word document, in a Textbox for example.

```
Public Function Foo()
    Dim WScript As String
    WScript = ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Set Bar = CreateObject(WScript)
    Dim Notepad As String
    Notepad = ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Bar.Run (Notepad)
End Function
```

Text Box 1 and Text Box 2 contain exactly the same strings as before, and I can read them with MsgBox(), but now the macro fails the CreateObject call on line 4 with the error: "Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create an object"

If I replace the string into the macro to let the code run past this point and create the WScript ActiveX object, I get an error when I call the Bar.Run method: "Run-time error '424': Object required".

This makes me think that fetching strings at run-time is impossible. Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a carriage return on the end of that text.

Perhaps try a `Replace` to eliminate it:

```
WScript = ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
WScript = Replace(WScript, Chr(13), "")
```

And similarly for `Notepad`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue.
Using the following bit of code to do this without knowing the length of strings: 
myStr = Replace(myStr, vbCr, " ")
myStr = Replace(myStr, vbLf, " ")
myStr = Replace(myStr, vbCrLf, " ")

Comment: Great. Glad to help.